# sleep(int) code isn't executed in right order in C programing

Tags: gnome-terminal, c

I have some codes in my program. I'm trying to run Loading screen in Terminal by using sleep(int) in a for loop below but it doesn't do in the right order.
These are my codes:

```
void LOAD()
{
    change_Terminal_Size(75 , 25);
    change_Background_To_Green();
    fill_The_Screen(75 , 25);
    int j;
    gotoxy(34,14); 
    change_Background_To_Black();
    printf(" LOADING....");
    for(j = 30 ; j <= 50; j++)
    {
        gotoxy(j,13);
        printf(" ");
        sleep(1);
    }
    gotoxy(34,14); printf(" COMPLETED  ");
    gotoxy(27,16); printf("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
}
```

```
void change_Terminal_Size(int width , int height)
{
    printf("\e[8;%d;%dt" , height , width);
}
```

```
void change_Background_To_Green()
{
    printf("\033[42m");
}
```

```
void fill_The_Screen(int width , int length)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < width ; i++)
    for(int j = 0 ; j < length ; j++)
    printf("%c" , 32);
}
```

```
void change_Background_To_Black()
{
    printf("\033[40m");
}
```

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, y, x);
}
```

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8luB.png) [Running sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az7no.png) [The code's done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMlnG.png)

Help me be clear!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep()` is executed whenever required, but `printf()` doesn't print the characters immediately. It buffers the output until a newline is encountered. You should `fflush(3)` it. See the `stdio(3)` manual page for details.

If you're doing screen manipulation like this, you might want to take a look at the `ncurses` library rather than manually doing all this.

Also note that setting the window size only works in several terminals, and is arguable bad practice. A well written app should work with whatever reasonable window size it gets.